# Can I rename a file that contains a forward slash in Unix?

Tags: unix, filenames

I am trying to rename a file with a name that contains the "/" character. 
Example:

```
mv product.dat product/2012.dat
```

Is this possible in Unix?

Comment: Such a file can't exist (/ separates directories and files in paths), so you can't.

Answer (score 4):

A `/` isn't allowed as a character in a file or directory name under Unix.  The `/` is understood as punctuation between directory levels in a complete path.  What you can do is create a directory called `product`, then move your file into it (which could be what you actually intended anyway.)

```
mkdir product
mv product.dat product/2012.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying you want to remove the '/' or add it? To remove it (however the heck it got there), use single quotes.

If you are trying to add it, then no, you cannot and should not.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any Unix with a filesystem that supports a `/` character in a filename. `/` is used to separate path entries, so it cannot be used in a filename.

Comment: You can mount FAT filesystems. OK, you still can't use /, but that's not because of the filesystem.

Comment: @Isaac: I'm afraid to disagree. FAT doesn't support `/` in filenames regardless of what OS is used to mount it. In particular, As soon as it supported subdirectories, MS-DOS internally accepted `/` as a path separator as a synonymous of  the documented `\`.

Comment: @jlliagre Don't be afraid to disagree, especially when you're right.